# Bare bones code of jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Can anyone provide the bare bones code needed to create jquery tabs please?

I am simply looking for just the basic code with 2 tabs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery tabs query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869268/jquery-tabs-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a look at the most simple example on the jQuery UI tabs page? There's even a "View source" link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#tabs').tabs();
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
        tab 1 content
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        tab 2 content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to include any libraries and css? I'm just getting a list of 2 items, no tabs. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find the code in the official documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ Just use the "View source" button.