# How is a HTML text box created, that has a horizontal menu tabs at the top to choose from?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, tabs

I hope my question isn't confusing anyone. I don't know what exactly is that sort of text box called :(
What I am looking for is to create a HTML text box that has different menus at its top i.e. the dimensions of the text box remains the same but each menu heading in the text box would have some text under it, that would open when a user clicks it.

Let me show you the demo:
http://www.e-conservationline.com/content/view/28/113/

Scroll down a bit on the page and have a look at **GENERAL RULES OF SUBMISSION:**
having menus like **Language**, **Word limit**, **copyright** etc

How can I create a similar type of text box, which I fill with text for each heading menu?

Comment: Those are called tabs.  How you actually implement them depends on a number of factors, depending on whether you want to write your own JavaScript, use jQuery, or use custom controls.

Comment: This is a *tabbed content* setup. If you search for that, lots will come up. If you have a go at something, and post what you've found/come up with, we will happily help if something's not working.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869268/jquery-tabs-query

Comment: Thank you @saluce :)
Atleast now I know what they are called - Tabs :D 
Hmm, I went through the links. So I guess one will have to use jquery for that. Let me try then. I hope it comes out well enough. Thank you everyone, thank you once again :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use some Javascript solution to achieve this goal. For instance, JQuery UI has a [tabs feature](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

For the same height, a little bit of CSS will satisfy you! ;)

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Peticolas :) yeah, this is exactly what I was looking for but how is it done? :(

Comment: I did not dive into JQuery's code, but I think they play with *display* CSS property. Visible tab related content display is set to block, the other ones to none. And with some click events set on each tabs, it should work.

Comment: Let me give a try... hoping for the best

Answer (score 1):

Each "textbox" has a button (by the way its not textbox, it's a div). For example

- div #1 has button 1
- div #2 has button 2
- ... so on

Only a div is shown at the time. When user click on a button, it show a div related to that button and hide all the rest. That's how it works